# What are the units of constraint 'points' in autolayout?

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to update an app to use `autolayout` and I am wondering what units are used to specify constraints.  They are referred to as points.  But are they pixels?  That would seem to defeat the intended utility of `autolayout`.  Do points map to pixels in a consistent way?  Can one set the units anywhere?  Using percentages strikes me as potentially very helpful.  I haven't been able to find the official definition anywhere.

UPDATE: I found part of the information and put it as an answer.  This actually makes me more confused: if you put two buttons with a separation constraint of 10 points, the on-screen separation is different for iPhone vs iPad (they appear closer on iPad since 10/ 768 is less than 10/320).  Is there a way around this using Interface Builder (i.e. avoiding coding the constraints?).

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I found part of the answer.  It's [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW15)

Comment: This could be improved by explaining the answer in addition to providing a link.